# Javascript if and switch statements

Tags: javascript

We have an existing carpet cleaning area calculator that I am needing assistance editing the code.

The calculator is currently operates if MOVE_FURNITURE_NO or MOVE_FURNITURE_EMPTY is checked, the price to clean is discounted by 20%. If Fiber protector, scotchgard, or decon is checked they are charged a price per sqft with a min of $25.

Here are the checkboxes on the form I am having the problem with:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="FIBER_PROTECTOR" /> Fiber ProTector  
<input type="checkbox" id="SCOTCHGARD" /> Scotchgard  
<input type="checkbox" id="DECON" /> Decontaminate & Deodorize  
<input type="checkbox" id="MOVE_FURNITURE_EMPTY" /> No, The Room Is Empty  
<input type="checkbox" id="MOVE_FURNITURE_NO" /> No, Clean Around It
```

Now we are trying to update the for so when "MOVE_FURNITURE_NO" is checked AND one, any, or all of DECON, FIBER PROTECTOR, or SCOTCHGARD is checked, they should be 20% off.

But...

When "MOVE_FURNITURE_EMPTY" is checked and one, any, or all of DECON, FIBER PROTECTOR, or SCOTCHGARD is checked, they should be full price.

These are the Javascript calculations that I have currently:

```
if (options.FIBER_PROTECTOR == 'on') total += Math.max(sq * FIBER_PROTECTOR, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);  
if (options.SCOTCHGARD == 'on') total += Math.max(sq * SCOTCHGARD, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);  
if (options.DECON == 'on') total += Math.max(sq * DECON, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);
```

I tried this code but the calculations are adding all three together and not conditionally:

```
if (options.MOVE_FURNITURE_NO == 'on' || options.FIBER_PROTECTOR == 'on') total += Math.max(sq * .032 / FIBER_PROTECTOR, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);  
if (options.MOVE_FURNITURE_NO == 'on' || options.SCOTCHGARD == 'on') total += Math.max(sq * .032 / SCOTCHGARD, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);  
if (options.MOVE_FURNITURE_NO == 'on' || options.DECON == 'on') total += Math.max(sq * .032 / DECON, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);
```

In the price breakdown section of the site should also calculate the same pricing, here is the current code we are using:

```
      if (item_val == 'on') {
        switch (optname) {
          case 'FIBER_PROTECTOR': 
            ul += '<span class="price_breakdown">$' + Math.max(sq_ft * FIBER_PROTECTOR, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN).toFixed(2) + '</span>';
            break;
          case 'SCOTCHGARD': 
            ul += '<span class="price_breakdown">$' + Math.max(sq_ft * SCOTCHGARD, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN).toFixed(2) + '</span>';
            break;
          case 'DECON': 
            ul += '<span class="price_breakdown">$' + Math.max(sq_ft * DECON, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN).toFixed(2) + '</span>';
            break;
```

I know this is a lot to ask but thank you in advanced for helping out.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL? It's all Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you need to apply the discount when `MOVE_FURNITURE_NO` is checked **and** the other options are checked. But your code uses **or** rather than **and**. You should use `||` between the other options to see if any of them is set, and then `&&` with `MOVE_FURNITURE_NO`.

In my code below, I've don't do the price calculation in the big `if`, I just set a `discount` variable. Then I use that when adding the price of each option to the total.

```
if (options.MOVE_FURNITURE_NO == 'on' && options.MOVE_FURNITURE_EMPTY != 'on' &&
        (options.FIBER_PROTECTOR == 'on' ||
         options.SCOTCHGARD == 'on' ||
         options.DECON == 'on')) {
    discount = 0.32; // reduced price
} else {
    discount = 1; // full price
}
if (options.FIBER_PROTECTOR == 'on') total += Math.max(discount * sq * FIBER_PROTECTOR, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);  
if (options.SCOTCHGARD == 'on') total += Math.max(discount * sq * SCOTCHGARD, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);  
if (options.DECON == 'on') total += Math.max(discount * sq * DECON, OTHER_SERVICES_MIN);
```

You can use the same `discount` variable in the `case` statements as well when you're displaying the itemized breakdown.

BTW, when you're representing on/off values in code, you should use boolean values `true` and `false`. Then you can simply write `options.OPTION_NAME` instead of `options.OPTION_NAME == 'on'`.

Comment: thank you, I will try this out. The code/calculator was already set up like this years ago and now I have to modify the code to what we need now. I will definitely keep the suggestions you mentioned in mind when I create something in the future.